# vue.js code, template and css in separate files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to split up my vue components to separate files that contain css (scss), template and code. The solution I have so far is:

The js code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import template from './template.vue';
import style from './style.vue';

import SubComponent from './SubComponent';

const component = {
  components: {
    SubComponent,
  },
  // other stuff like methods, watch ...
};
export default Vue.component('Component', {
  ...component,
  ...template,
  ...style,
});
```

The css:

```
<style lang="scss">
some-class {
  background: green;
}
</style>
```

The template:

```
<template>
  <div class="some-class">
    <SubComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

I wonder if this is the way to do it or if there is a better/common way to do it.

**Scoped css**

For scoped style I do the following:
file: style.module.scss

```
someClass {
  background: green;
}
```

In Component.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import template from './template.vue';
import style from './style.module.scss';

import SubComponent from './SubComponent';

const component = {
  components: {
    SubComponent,
  },
  data: () => ({ style }),
  // other stuff like methods, watch ...
};
export default Vue.component('Component', {
  ...component,
  ...template,
  ...style,
});
```

And template.vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:class="[style.someClass]">
    <SubComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

I would not recommend trying the following:

```
<template src="./path/component.html" />
<script src="./path/component.vue" />
<style lang="scss" src="./path/component.scss />
```

The [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns) provides an example where template does not have a src property [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/issues/35#issuecomment-161436380) is Evan saying you can give it a src property but it looks like it breaks [module reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59610257/1641941).

Comment: you can include common css in index.html file

Comment: const Foo = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-foo" */ './Foo.vue') This is written in the routing file.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Each component has scoped css, in react it would be `import style from 'style.moduce.scss'`. Each component needs a separate file for style, template and logic. This is because you can manipulate theme, behaviour and layout with env variable. So by changing an env variable before building I should be able to change the looks and the behaviour of the app without having to copy and paste 90% of the code in vue files that contain **everything** and instead have a container that composes a component out of imported styles, behaviour and templates.

Comment: @多一点点爱 Thank you for your comment but I don't know what you mean. I need the style, template and logic (javascript) of the component to be in different files so I can create a container that imports them and can compose a component that looks or behaves differently without having to re write shared code in all the vue files that contain all the code.

Comment: @HMR The method described above is the vue-router lazy loading, which USES webpack to pack the components corresponding to each route into separate js and CSS files, and the HTML will not be packaged separately.

Comment: @HMR In a new project built with @vue/cli, There are examples above, I don't think HTML and JS can be completely separated because vue itself requires JS to create and update the DOM.

Comment: @HMR This address can be referred to https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk

Comment: @多一点点爱 You say `I don't think HTML and JS can be completely separated` but did you read the question? It has an example of the script and template in separate files. As I have it now it works, not as good as it would in React but still. Even scoping css to a component is possible. I'm not sure if this is the intended way because vue documentation is a disorganised mess and just documents whatever the writer felt like writing that day instead of (for example) documenting all that can be passed to vue.component

Comment: @HMR You want to write your code separately, not separately by packaging it.I haven't tried. I'll try.

Comment: @HMR I found a way，https://github.com/pksunkara/vue-builder-webpack-plugin Look at this Whether it can meet your needs

Comment: @多一点点爱 Thank you, that looks promising but a vue project doesn't have a webpack.config so I'm not sure what config the author of that project is talking about.

Comment: @HMR People have asked similar questions before, and here's their discussion https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/issues/35 @vue/cli3.0 use webpack https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html

Comment: @多一点点爱 Looks like `<template src="./path/component.html" />
<script src="./path/component.vue" />
<style lang="scss" src="./path/component.scss />` works as well. I am using `@vue/cli-service` version `3.11.0`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns

Comment: @str That doesn't have template in a separate file so I thought src property is not possible on template. But as with everything vue documentation related one must just try it and hope it keeps working.

Comment: @HMR Here is an example of the creation of vue-cli2.0 https://github.com/1166544/vue-split-css-html-js-files But it's in Chinese, you can refer to it