# Seemingly random lint errors in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I run `yarn serve` (executes `vue-cli-service serve`) it builds without errors, then I edit and save Component.vue I get the following errors and or warning (it's both a warning and an error for some reason):

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: The template root requires exactly one element (vue/valid-template-root) at src/Component.vue:1:1:
> 1 | <template scr="./template.html" />
    | ^
  2 | <script src="./script.js" />
  3 |
```

And I get:

```
error: clear (vue/comment-directive) at src/Component.vue:1:64:
> 1 | <template scr="./template.html" />
    |                                   ^
  2 | <script src="./script.js" />
  3 |
```

According to yarn.lock I am using version 3.11.0 of vue-cli-service

```
"@vue/cli-service@^3.9.0":
  version "3.11.0"
```

Comment: Is it possible that it is linting the output directory (the generated code)?

Comment: Not sure whether self-closing tags are supported. The typo in `scr` is also likely to be a problem.

Comment: @SanderSluis I don't think so, it won't build anything when these warning errors occur, changes in the code is not reflected in the browser and nothing is hot reloaded. Maybe it's because you can/cannot have a src property on template (depending what part of the documentation or issues of vue you read you can and at the same time cannot give template a src property)

Comment: @skirtle Initial build works but when I change code it rebuilds for hot module reloading and that fails guess I just keep using it the [other way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59577062/1641941)

Comment: So you see the same error even if you fix the problems I described?

Comment: @skirtle `Not sure whether self-closing tags are supported.` How can you be sure of anything with the state that vue documentation is in? I'm not even sure src property is supported for template tag since that's not documented anywhere either. It may be a caching problem because after a reboot the problem went away. Try to reproduce but am unable to.